# Calc: How to convert a numeric column in-place?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

In Libreoffice Calc, is there a way to convert a column of numbers "in-place", such as converting from miles to kilometers, or percent to decimal?

I know how to do it by: adding a temporary column, applying a formula, copying the new column, paste-special onto the old column, deleting the temporary column.

So the keyword is "in-place", to avoid the addition/deletion of the temporary column.

Comment: Percent to decimal is just a format change, you can do this in-place by simply selecting the column and changing the data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If adding one cell value is acceptable**: enter the conversion factor in any empty cell (even on another sheet), select `Paste Special`, and select the approrpriate calculation below of `Transpose`.

E.g., to convert between inches and centimeters:

1. enter the factor 2.54 in an empty cell;
2. copy that cell;
3. select the values to convert;
4. Menu `Edit` -> `Paste Special`;
5. Under `Operations`, select the arithmetic operation to use; for in -> cm, select `multiply`; for cm to in, select `divide`:

   [image]

**Without any modification of the sheet's content:** then you'll have to create a macro that applies a pre-defined arithmetic operation on every cell in a defined / selected range.

Comment: @cwackers: hmm, you're right - my answer is a little bit terse - but im'm happy it helped anyway. I've added the steps and a screenshot.